# Select table from another DB in stored procedure don't work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query which works fine. I must made a join with a table from another DB, as you can see below: takacs.TecDocB4.dbo

```
SELECT
TYP_ID as ID,
MFA_ID as ModelID,
concat(DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT, ' / ', TYP_KW_FROM)  + 'KW' + ' / ' + DES_TEXTS3.TEX_TEXT as Name    
FROM
takacs.TecDocB4.dbo.TYPES
INNER JOIN MODELS ON MOD_ID = TYP_MOD_ID
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURERS ON MFA_ID = MOD_MFA_ID
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS AS COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS2 ON COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS2.CDS_ID = MOD_CDS_ID AND COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS2.CDS_LNG_ID = 21
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS ON COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_ID = TYP_CDS_ID AND COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_LNG_ID = 21
INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS.CDS_TEX_ID
 LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = TYP_KV_ENGINE_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 21
 LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS2 ON DES_TEXTS2.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
 LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS2 ON DESIGNATIONS2.DES_ID = TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID AND DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID = 21
 LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS3 ON DES_TEXTS3.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS2.DES_TEX_ID

WHERE
TYP_MOD_ID = 504;
```

Now I need to transform this query in a stored procedure, but I keep getting some errors as you can see in the attached screenshot:

[image]

It says that has an unresolved reference to object takacs.TecDocB4.dbo.TYPES. Can you please help me on this? 
Why it is working as a query? and as a stored procedure it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's as easy as giving aliases to your tables. At [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1148746-392-1.aspx) thread I read that querying linked servers might require aliases for tables. Cit.
`"Actually, should mention the following if your query uses joins between tables from linked server and other, every table in the query should be given an aliase."`

Comment: Have you tried escaping the reserved word Types with [Types]

Comment: I've tried to use alialses, I've tried to escape the word Types:[takacs].[TecDocB4].[dbo].[TYPES] as t, but I get the same error :(